# Работа с объектом $resource

Tags: angularjs

Добрый день.
В AngulaJS новичок.
Подскажите, что делаю не так.

Есть фабрика:

```
.factory('restFactory', ['$resource', 'SERVER_API', function ($resource, SERVER_API) {

        return $resource(SERVER_API + '/api_demo/:type_request.php',
            {type_request: '@type_request'},
            {
                query: {
                    method: 'GET',
                    isArray: false
                },
                get: {
                    method: 'GET',
                    //cache: true
                }
            }
        );


    }])
```

Использование фабрики в контроллере:

```
function NotesListCtrl ($scope, $rootScope, $http, $log, restFactory) {

    var vm = this;

    $scope.moduleSettings = {
        moduleName : 'notes',
        pageTitle : 'Список записей'
    };

    vm.item = {};

    vm.item = restFactory.get({type_request:'request_notes'});

    $log.debug(vm.item);

}
```

Вопрос:
Как получить доступ к данным (vm.item.items[0].id) в контролере, где используется фабрика?
В представлении могу обратиться к любому объекту и массиву
{{vm.item.items[0].id}}.

Если пишу:

```
vm.item = restFactory.get({type_request:'request_notes'});
$log.debug(vm.item.items[0].id);
```

значение **undefined**

Что делаю не так? В какую сторону копать?

Репозиторий:
https://bitbucket.org/esivanov87/workbook-notes/src

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так как внутри `$resource` используется тот же самый `$http`, то получить доступ к возвращенным элементам сразу - нельзя.

#### Как работают методы `$resource`?

При вызове метода, посылается запрос, при этом возвращается объект заглушка с полем `$promise`, в котором хранится результат запроса. Как только был получен ответ, содержимое данного объекта заменяется на полученное.

Таким образом нельзя сразу обратиться к результату, так как в это время он еще не получен.

Для решения можно либо использовать свойство `$promise`, добавив котором обработчик `then` внутри можно получить доступ к результату.

Либо можно использовать `success callback` при вызове метода

```
vm.item = restFactory.get({type_request:'request_notes'}, function success(item){
    $log.debug(item.items[0].id);
    $log.debug(vm.item.items[0].id);
});
```

Comment: Спасибо вам. Немного начинаю понимать. У меня есть переменная до это кода var itemId.  хочу записать в неё itemID = vm.item.items[0].id и использовать дальше по коду. но она по-прежнему undefined. Можете с этим помочь? переменная вроде объявлена до function success...